# What's the difference between these two sentences in English?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, difference, expressions

In the sentences below:

> 1. 'It's only a suggestion.'
> 2. 'That's only a suggestion.'

I was told by most people that they could be used interchangeably, but I believe they exist for some reason that yet to be found out.

How do you differentiate them?

Comment: Both _that_ and _it_ are used here to refer to the same thing. So it is interchangeable for this example.

Comment: [Related on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/113649/that-vs-it-as-anaphoric-determiners)

Answer (score 1):

You can use either "it" or "that" to refer to the thing that has just been written or talked about.  The usage of the former is more common; however, the latter is more emphatic.